# I can't load data with Handsontable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an application in Django (using Django Rest Framework in Backend) and Front (django templates with Jquery). I've tried load information in Handsontable library but when I tried to load It showed me error message.

> Uncaught Error: loadData only accepts array of objects or array of
>   arrays (string given)

My json is:

```
{
"description": "[{\"data\": \"CEA\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"CROTAL\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NOMBRE\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. NACIMIENTO\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. PARTO\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NP\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. ANALISIS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"LECHE\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%G\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%P\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"RCS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"DIAS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"LE AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%G AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%P AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}]",
"typeset": 0,
"titles": "[\"CEA\", \"CROTAL\", \"NOMBRE\", \"D. NACIMIENTO\", \"D. PARTO\", \"NP\", \"D. ANALISIS\", \"NC\", \"LECHE\", \"%G\", \"%P\", \"RCS\", \"DIAS\", \"LE AC\", \"%G AC\", \"%P AC\"]",
"ren": 3,
"error": 0,
"producciones": "[{\"cea\": 2785658758, \"crotal\": \"ES025986548856\", \"nombre\": 8856, \"fchNaci\": \"None\", \"dparto\": \"2014-09-01 00:00:00\", \"np\": 2, \"danalisis\": \"2014-12-15 00:00:00\", \"nc\": 0.2, \"leche\": 32, \"pg\": 3.75, \"pp\": 3.27, \"rcs\": 201, \"dias\": 81, \"le_ac\": 2870, \"pgac\": 4.41, \"ppac\": 3.24}, {\"cea\": 2785658758, \"crotal\": 2785658758, \"nombre\": \"1111 MALU\", \"fchNaci\": \"None\", \"dparto\": \"2014-01-15 00:00:00\", \"np\": 3, \"danalisis\": \"2014-12-15 00:00:00\", \"nc\": 0.9, \"leche\": 36.5, \"pg\": 2.88, \"pp\": 3.28, \"rcs\": 21, \"dias\": 165, \"le_ac\": 11286, \"pgac\": 5.15, \"ppac\": 3.45}]",
"col": 13
}
```

And my function in Jquery is:

```
function processHandsontable(data) {
        var hstSelctors = ["#gridxls", "#xlssal"];
        var content = JSON.parse(data);
        var $container;
        if (content.error != 0) {
            sweetAlert("Error", "No information", "error");
        } else {
            $container = $(hstSelctors[content.typeset]);
            var datos = content.producciones; 
            $container.handsontable({
                startRows: content.ren,
                startCols: content.col,
                colHeaders: content.titles,
                columns: content.description,
                data: datos
            });
        }
    }
```

I don't know where is the error

Comment: Do you have the line number where error is raised?

Comment: the error is located in `data: datos`

Comment: As the error message says, `datos` should be either array of objects OR array of array. Currently it is a json object. wrap that json object with`[ ]` so that it is a json array

Comment: @SG_ thank you, with your answer I could see the problem I didn't need [ ], Simply convert to object the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `datos` should be either array of objects OR array of array. Currently it is a json object. Use a json array as `data` in the options to `handsontable()` function. Change the `datos` like this

```
  [{
"description": "[{\"data\": \"CEA\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"CROTAL\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NOMBRE\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. NACIMIENTO\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. PARTO\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NP\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"D. ANALISIS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"NC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"LECHE\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%G\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%P\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"RCS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"DIAS\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"LE AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%G AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}, {\"data\": \"%P AC\", \"type\": \"text\"}]",
"typeset": 0,
"titles": "[\"CEA\", \"CROTAL\", \"NOMBRE\", \"D. NACIMIENTO\", \"D. PARTO\", \"NP\", \"D. ANALISIS\", \"NC\", \"LECHE\", \"%G\", \"%P\", \"RCS\", \"DIAS\", \"LE AC\", \"%G AC\", \"%P AC\"]",
"ren": 3,
"error": 0,
"producciones": "[{\"cea\": 2785658758, \"crotal\": \"ES025986548856\", \"nombre\": 8856, \"fchNaci\": \"None\", \"dparto\": \"2014-09-01 00:00:00\", \"np\": 2, \"danalisis\": \"2014-12-15 00:00:00\", \"nc\": 0.2, \"leche\": 32, \"pg\": 3.75, \"pp\": 3.27, \"rcs\": 201, \"dias\": 81, \"le_ac\": 2870, \"pgac\": 4.41, \"ppac\": 3.24}, {\"cea\": 2785658758, \"crotal\": 2785658758, \"nombre\": \"1111 MALU\", \"fchNaci\": \"None\", \"dparto\": \"2014-01-15 00:00:00\", \"np\": 3, \"danalisis\": \"2014-12-15 00:00:00\", \"nc\": 0.9, \"leche\": 36.5, \"pg\": 2.88, \"pp\": 3.28, \"rcs\": 21, \"dias\": 165, \"le_ac\": 11286, \"pgac\": 5.15, \"ppac\": 3.45}]",
"col": 13
}]
```